# Extract standard errors from lm object

Tags: r, regression, lm, standard-error

We got a *lm* object from and want to extract the standard error

```
lm_aaa <- lm(aaa ~ x + y + z)
```

I know the function summary, names and coefficients.

However, summary seems to be the only way to manually access the standard error.

Have you any idea how I can just output *se*?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The output of from the `summary` function is just an R **list**. So you can use all the standard list operations. For example:

```
#some data (taken from Roland's example)
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(2.1,3.9,6.3,7.8)

#fitting a linear model
fit = lm(y~x)
m = summary(fit)
```

The `m` object or list has a number of attributes. You can access them using the bracket or named approach:

```
m$sigma
m[[6]]
```

A handy function to know about is, `str`. This function provides a summary of the objects attributes, i.e.

```
str(m)
```

Comment: However, what @csgillespie refers to is the **residual** standard deviation of the model, not the standard deviation of the individual coefficients. The function `m$sigma` corresponds to `sigma(fit)`, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/sigma.html). I believe the question was really about the standard deviation of the **individual** coefficients.

Answer (score 13):

To get a list of the standard errors for all the parameters, you can use

```
summary(lm_aaa)$coefficients[, 2]
```

As others have pointed out, `str(lm_aaa)` will tell you pretty much all the information that can be extracted from your model.

Answer (score 11):

```
#some data
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
y<-c(2.1,3.9,6.3,7.8)

#fitting a linear model
fit<-lm(y~x)

#look at the statistics summary
summary(fit)

#get the standard error of the slope
se_slope<-summary(fit)$coef[[4]] 
#the index depends on the model and which se you want to extract

#get the residual standard error
rse<-summary(fit)$sigma
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to get the standard error/deviation of the **model**, but instead the standard error/deviation of the **individual coefficients**, use

```
# some data (taken from Roland's example)
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y = c(2.1, 3.9, 6.3, 7.8)

# fitting a linear model
fit = lm(y ~ x)

# get vector of all standard errors of the coefficients
coef(summary(fit))[, "Std. Error"]
```

For more information on the standard error/deviation of the model, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/sigma.html). For more information on the standard error/deviation of the coefficients, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/coef.html).

Answer (score 5):

I think that the following lines can also provide you with a quick answer:

```
lm_aaa<- lm(aaa~x+y+z)
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(lm_aaa)))
```